# How to create a sticky footer in CSS inside an absolutely positioned div?

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a sticky footer *inside* an absolutely positioned div element.

My approach was to position the footer div absolutely as well - inside an additional relatively positioned "page" div (which would contain the actual content of the page):

```
<div class="content">
   <div class="page">
      ...Some Lorem ipsum content...
      <div class="footer">Some footer</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

with the following styles:

```
.content {
     position: absolute;
     top: 60px;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
}

.page {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.footer {
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

This method doesn't work very well since the footer overlaps the text at a certain level when you resize the page.
How can I get rid of this overlapping behaviour?

A more detailed, working example with the full layout: https://jsfiddle.net/8nrukse9/2/

Comment: That's an awful lot of absolute positioning...there are much more flexible layout methods.

Comment: Thanks, could you give me some hints which layout methods do you prefer over absolute positioning? I usually use [this](http://stevesanderson.github.io/fixed-height-layouts-demo/two-columns.html) layout example in my projects as a starting point because I usually create web applications where every page has some fixed layout elements (menus, headers, etc.)

Comment: Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: This means that it cannot be done using the current layout?

Comment: Oh...I was afraid that you will mention flexbox...Unfortunately I have to support IE9 as well, that's why I've never used it... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change CSS

```
    .page{height: 100%;}
  .page-inner {
    margin-bottom:-30px;
    min-height: 100%;


  }
  .page-inner:after{height:30px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
  .footer {
    height: 30px;
    color: brown;
    border: 1px solid brown;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8nrukse9/5/

Comment: So you try to compensate the bottom padding with a negative margin? Good idea, but as I can see, it doesn't work, I think because the footer is positioned absolutely to the bottom...
In your link, the scrollbar appears automatically, which is weird, I would expect that the scrollbar should only appear when it's needed...

Comment: change min height .page (min-height: 96%;)

Comment: Using min-height: 96% is a very ad-hoc workaround, I need a proper solution.

Comment: *Note*: I only choose this as a solution because of IE9 support. Otherwise I would use the flexbox way.

Answer (score 3):

The only method I can think of here is `flexbox` and not absolute positioning.

```
  .page {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .footer {
    margin-top: auto;
    height: 30px;
    color: brown;
    border: 1px solid brown;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  }
```

```css
body {
  color: white;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav .logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: salmon;
}
nav .navmenu {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content-wrapper .header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: pink;
}
.content-wrapper .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: rosybrown;
}
.content-wrapper .page {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}
.content-wrapper .footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  height: 30px;
  color: brown;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">Logo</div>
  <ul class="navmenu">
    <li>Start page</li>
    <li>Menu item 1</li>
    <li>Menu item 2</li>
    <li>Menu item 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="page">

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore quis, temporibus, accusamus facere exercitationem molestiae reprehenderit alias dignissimos quo voluptates deleniti consequatur sunt sequi doloremque dolorem voluptatem ea voluptatum qui.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore quis, temporibus, accusamus facere exercitationem molestiae reprehenderit alias dignissimos quo voluptates deleniti consequatur sunt sequi doloremque dolorem voluptatem ea voluptatum
      qui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore quis, temporibus, accusamus facere exercitationem molestiae reprehenderit alias dignissimos quo voluptates deleniti consequatur sunt sequi doloremque dolorem voluptatem ea voluptatum
      qui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore quis, temporibus, accusamus facere exercitationem molestiae reprehenderit alias dignissimos quo voluptates deleniti consequatur sunt sequi doloremque dolorem voluptatem ea voluptatum
      qui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore quis, temporibus, accusamus facere exercitationem molestiae reprehenderit alias dignissimos quo voluptates deleniti consequatur sunt sequi doloremque dolorem voluptatem ea voluptatum
      qui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore quis, temporibus, accusamus facere exercitationem molestiae reprehenderit alias dignissimos quo voluptates deleniti consequatur sunt sequi doloremque dolorem voluptatem ea voluptatum
      qui.

      <div class="footer">Some footer - it shouldn't overlap with the content if you resize the page</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this work under IE9? I guess not, because of [flexbox](https://www.bhalash.com/archives/13544804709)...

Answer (score 1):

As the browser window resizes, the footer `height` in CSS will dynamically change. Flexbox takes care of that, older CSS layouts are not able to do so.

IF IE9 support is a must, I'd determine the footer `min-height` offset with jQuery dynamically by calculating the height of `.footer` .

```
var footerHeight = $( "footer" ).height();
$(".page").css("min-height", footerHeight);
```

Comment: I see the problem now, thanks for the explanation. IE9 support is officially a must for me, unfortunately...Although I don't think anybody actually use it :) 
I think I will use a workaround by @Lalji Tadhani, because I feel it's more clean than the JS correction. In this workaround the height of the footer is compensated by an additional element's margin. See his answer for the actual solution.

Comment: Yeah his answer is pretty good, so is Paulie_D's. All three of these methods will actually work.